# Understanding the difference between interface and objects in DOM

Tags: javascript, object, dom, interface

What is the difference between interfaces and objects in the context of the document object model?
This is what my current understanding is. Please correct me if I am wrong.
**Interface**:-Interface only defines different parts in the DOM. What properties they have, what methods they have, and so on. Interfaces are defined using interface defining languages.
**Objects**:-Objects are used to implement those specification specifies by interfaces.

*Note*:- I am a beginner in javascript and trying to understand how interfaces are related to DOM and Javascript

Answer (score 1):

A good example to start with is the [HTMLTableElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement) Interface

When you use :

```
const myTable = document.createElement('table');
```

the browser knows from the tag name which interface to use and returns an object with the properties and methods from that interface.

Now we can do:

```
const row = myTable.createRow()
```

which is a method defined by the HTMLTableElement interface and uses the [HTMLTableRowElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement) interface to create the new row object inserted into the table.

Combining it together using javascript to completely build a table:

```js
const myTable = document.createElement('table');
// set some property values on the object
myTable.border = 1;
// add a <caption>
const cap = myTable.createCaption();
cap.textContent = 'My Cool Table'

// create some rows
for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
   const row = myTable.insertRow()
   // use inertCells() defined in HTMLTableRowElement interface
   for( let j=0; j < 3; j++){
      // new cell object has been inserted
      const cell = row.insertCell();
      // set properties of the cell object
      cell.textContent = `${i+1}:${j+1}`
   }   
}

// finally insert the whole table object into the dom
document.body.append(myTable)

// Read some properties of the table object
//like how many rows in table
console.log('# of rows in myTable =', myTable.rows.length)
// what's the caption text
console.log('Caption says: ', myTable.caption.textContent)
```

```css
td{ width: 30px}
```

Comment: So an interface is kind of like a class in object-oriented programming?

Comment: In this case yes. Good analogy

Comment: Feel free to accept this answer if it helped